# jquery ajax call return 403 forbidden error in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this ajax call work fine in firefox and chrome but in internet explorer it's response is "403 forbidden". and i am making this call on same domain. I am getting response untill whole page is loaded but after that i get 403 forbidden error.

```
$.ajax(

{
url : "gettwitt.php?val=0&media=med-16,
type : "GET",
cache   : "false",
dataType : "json",
success : function(n)
{
  alert(n);
}
});
```

you can check it out at http://indiantweets.in

Answer (score 2):

```
url : "gettwitt.php?val=0&media=med-16",
///                                   ^ Add a " there, like I have done.
```

You have failed to close the string with a matching delimiter. Add a closing `"` to your first string.

Also `false` and `"false"` are two different things, with the latter being equivalent to `true` (as it is a non empty `String`) and *not* `false`. Drop the quotes there.